# Make a sub application independent form the root application in iis 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2012

I am new to IIS and I have two asp .net mvc applications that are completely independent of each other, but because both of them are going public, I have to put them under the same port 443. So I created one application as a child of the other.

https://localhost
https://localhost/admin

The problem now, is the sub application https://localhost/admin inheriting from the root application which will miss things up. Is there any way that I can make them completely independent from each other?

applicationhost.config

```
    <site name="mulkiaportal" id="4" serverautostart="false"> 
         <application path="/" applicationpool="mulkiaportal"> 
             <virtualdirectory path="/" physicalpath="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mulkia\portal2\portal\moj.portal" />
         </application> 
         <application path="/admin" applicationpool="mulkiaapp" enabledprotocols="http"> 
             <virtualdirectory path="/" physicalpath="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mulkia\portal2\portal\app\moj.application" logonmethod="cleartext" />
         </application> 
         <bindings> 
            <binding protocol="https" bindinginformation="localhost:443:" sslflags="0" /> 
         </bindings>
     </site>
```

Comment: You should not nest applications in IIS. Add app1 to http://localhost/app1 and app2 to http://localhost/app2. Then you can add a redirect setting for http://localhost so that users are taken to the appropriate one.

Comment: Two sites can share the same ports, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background So host the two MVC web apps in their own sites please.

Answer (score 0):

You can run IIS multiple websites on port 443, IIS will be able to host multiple websites. Up until IIS 3, each website needs to have a dedicated IP address. From IIS 5, Microsoft introduced a concept of host header. With the host header, we can host multiple websites using a single IP address.

1.Create a domain from IIS

To create a domain from IIS, you can Click on Start >>Administrative Tools >> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. Now right-click on Sites and click Add website. Now a window appears. We enter the site name. It will automatically fill the application pool column with the respective website name.Then, enter the physical path of the website files. Select the protocol type as HTTP and select the IP address from the drop-down list.In the hostname column, enter the domain name. Finally, click ok.

[image]

2.Add host header

Now, we add the unique host header from binding. To create a unique hostname:
From IIS click on binding in the action column. Now edit the default entry in binding.
As a default, the hostname will be left blank.  Now, enter the Hostname. Finally, click ok.

[image]